# Installing packages on mac

Tags: errors, packages, mac

I have been trying to install the chemformula package on my mac but it keeps giving me this error:[image]

I have put my chemformula zip file in a texmf file:‎⁨ iCloud Drive⁩ ▸ ⁨Secretária⁩ ▸ ⁨texmf⁩ ▸ ⁨tex⁩ ▸ ⁨latex⁩, but it still gives me this error. I have also tried using the terminal to put that package but doesn't work as well. Please help!

Comment: The chemformula package must be unzipped and in the same folder of the document. (The alternative is to have the .sty files already in the system wide TeX collection. )  If unzipping the chem package doesn't work then a quick search (Google) finds the .sty file on CTan which then can be copied and stored.

Comment: @Leucippus Should i put the document in the same folder as the .sty file, for example also put it in the texmf file?

Comment: Yes, the document goes into the same file where the .sty file is. If it was my system I'd create, in the Latex folder, a folder named Chem. In Chem folder I'd have the unzipped ChemFormula package (including the .sty file) and any documents being worked on.

Comment: It still doesn't work...

Comment: It keeps giving me the same error...

Comment: Did you unzip the package `chemformula zip` ?

Comment: Yes i have it unzipped with the document. I'm thinking that for mac this package doesn't work but idk

Comment: An alternative is to get the `chemformula-manual.cls` and `chemformula.sty` from [CTan Chem...](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula?lang=en) and place that in the same file as the document.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm not gonna use that package as it doesn't work.. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: The `chemformula` folder you get when you unzip the downloaded file contains, among other things, chemformula.sty. Copy that file to the same folder as the document you are typesetting and try to typeset again. If that works come back for more information about where to put it.

Comment: I was only able to install it via texlive utility but thanks for the concern

Answer (score 1):

You have the BasicTeX package (https://tug.org/mactex) installed as can be seen in your screenshot.

It should be fairly simple to install additional packages via the "TeX Live Utility.app". Look for "chemformula" in the Packages tab, then right-click and select install.

[image: TeX Live Utility]

Comment: This worked thanks!!